# Separate Content for each different language in joomla

Tags: joomla

It is possible to get multiple input textareas where I can enter content for each language separately. Is there some kind of extension that enables this. I am a novice at joomla so please help me.

Well, something like

```
Title(English): <THEN A TEXT BOX HERE>
Title(Other Langauge): <THEN A TEXT BOX HERE>
Content(English):
<THEN A TEXTAREA HERE>
Content(Other Language)
<THEN ANOTHER TEXTAREA HERE>
```

I am just passing ideas. May be there is something better that can solve my problem. basically, i need to manually enter different content for every language installed. Not through automatic translation. It is not even available...

Comment: you need to supply more details, what would you want on the textareas? give an example please.

Comment: @jackjoe, seperate textarea for each langauges, where I can enter content in unicode separately

Comment: That's still too vague. Please explain a real example, and then I might be able to help (edit your post, instead of adding comments), the more detail you give, the better your answers will be. Also, what version of Joomla?

Comment: @jackJoe, I downloaded the latest joomla.... and please check my question, i have updated with something that might explain better.

Comment: you want the textarea to give you access to the content in other languages, is that it? you can try the very good multi-lingual component joomfish (http://www.joomfish.net/) but it isn't compatible with 1.6/7 yet, so you may need to try another one, have you tried searching the extension gallery at the joomla site? (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/multi-lingual-content)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Joomla Translations Manager - we use it on all our multilingual pages and it will help you translate JText::_() strings

Answer (score 0):

As JackJoe said, Joomfish is what you are looking for. http://www.joomfish.net/